# Escape special characters in different languages

Tags: javascript, regex

I use the following regular expression to escape special characters:

```
var searchForTest = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]/gi,'.');
```

This works correctly when the text is in English but fails when I am trying to highligh greek characters because they are identified as special characters.

Example of a working sample: [English Characters](http://jsfiddle.net/JEUcx/48/)

Example of a non working sample [Greek Characters](http://jsfiddle.net/JEUcx/52/)

Thanks

Comment: By "escape" it looks like you mean "trash"

Comment: I am not trashing the special characters. I replace them with a dot `.`

Comment: If you were escaping them then the process could be reversed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're dealing with greek symbols you should use unicode sequences instead.
Since greek symbols [are in range \u0374 - \u03FF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Greek_and_Coptic) just add this range into your regexp

```
var searchForTest = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.\u0374-\u03FF]/gi,'.');
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript regexes don't have any real understanding of Unicode; that is, there are no Unicode-aware character classes like "letter" or "digit" (there's only "ASCII alphanumeric character"), there's no way to refer to Unicode properties, etc. So you basically have two options:

- match any ASCII character that's not in your special subset:

  ```
  var searchForTest = text.replace(/(?=[\x20-\x7E])[^a-zA-Z 0-9.]/gi,'.');
  ```

  (This has the downside that it won't recognize curly-quotes, Greek-specific punctuation, etc., as special characters.)
- match any character that's not in your special subset, and adding Greek and other characters as you need them:

  ```
  var searchForTest = text.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.α-ωΑ-Ω]/gi,'.');
  ```

  (The downside of this is obvious.)

You can try to combine the above for a mixed approach, but you'll never get it perfect. :-/